# How do we know \$R_x=\frac{R_2R_3}{R_1}\$,and \$L_x=C_1R_2R_3\$ in the maxwell bridge

Tags: voltage, resistors, bridge-rectifier

There is a maxwell bridge below

[image]

The book said when

$$(R_1//\frac{1}{jwC_1})(R_x+jwL_x)=R_2R_3$$

We can find that \$R_x=\frac{R_2R_3}{R_1}\$, and \$L_x=C_1R_2R_3\$

I want to ask how can we mathematically manipulate this:

$$(R_1//\frac{1}{jwC_1})(R_x+jwL_x)=R_2R_3$$

To prove that:

$$R_x=\frac{R_2R_3}{R_1}$$

And:

$$L_x=C_1R_2R_3$$

Because i think we can't because of the imaginary number \$j\$.

Comment: Solve for a normal wheatstone bridge first. Should basically be the same thing.

Comment: For the bridge to be balanced, the products of opposite branches must be equal. In this particular case the product \$Z_x.Z_1\$ is real (imaginary part is zero), and  \$Z_x.Z_1=R_2.R_3\$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by calculating R1 in parallel with C (product over sum): -

$$\dfrac{\dfrac{R_1}{j\omega C}}{R_1 + \dfrac{1}{j\omega C}} \Rightarrow  \dfrac{R_1}{1 + j\omega CR_1}$$

Then, multiply top and bottom by: \$1 - j\omega CR_1\$ (this is called using the complex conjugate): -

$$\dfrac{R_1(1 - j\omega CR_1)}{1 + \omega^2 C^2R_1^2}$$

Then multiply by \$R_x + j\omega L\$ to get: -

$$\dfrac{R_1(R_x + j\omega L)(1 - j\omega CR_1)}{1 + \omega^2C^2R_1^2}$$

Notice here that there are complex terms only in the numerator and not the denominator. Notice also that these complex terms cannot equate to anything but zero because ultimately the bridge is in balance and the above formula equals \$R_2R_3\$ (no complex terms). So,

$$j\omega L = j\omega CR_xR_1$$

Hence \$L = CR_xR_1\$ and I think you can see that this agrees with your question's other solution if you accept that it is true: -

$$R_x=\dfrac{R_2R_3}{R_1}$$

Now I could go on here and prove that but I think you can take it from here. Let me know if you are confused.

Comment: thanks a lot,now i totally understand it!

Answer (score 0):

Well, we have the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOzzKt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The input resistance can be found:

$$\text{R}_\text{in}=\frac{\left(\text{R}_0+\text{R}_2\right)\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)}{\text{R}_0+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}\tag1$$

Now, the input current is given by:

$$\text{I}_\text{in}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{in}}{\text{R}_\text{in}}=\text{V}_\text{in}\cdot\frac{\text{R}_0+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}{\left(\text{R}_0+\text{R}_2\right)\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)}\tag2$$

Now, the current \$\text{I}_1\$ is given by:

$$\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}{\text{R}_0+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}\cdot\text{I}_\text{in}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{in}}{\text{R}_0+\text{R}_2}\tag3$$

Now, the current \$\text{I}_2\$ is given by:

$$\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{R}_0+\text{R}_2}{\text{R}_0+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}\cdot\text{I}_\text{in}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{in}}{\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}\tag4$$

So, we get:

- $$\text{V}_\text{A}=\text{I}_1\cdot\text{R}_2=\frac{\text{V}_\text{in}\text{R}_2}{\text{R}_0+\text{R}_2}\tag5$$
- $$\text{V}_\text{B}=\text{I}_2\cdot\text{R}_4=\frac{\text{V}_\text{in}\text{R}_4}{\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}\tag6$$

So, we also get:

$$\text{V}_\text{A}-\text{V}_\text{B}=\text{V}_\text{in}\cdot\left\{\frac{\text{R}_2}{\text{R}_0+\text{R}_2}-\frac{\text{R}_4}{\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}\right\}\tag7$$

---

When we set (where \$\text{j}^2=-1\$):

- $$\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{in}}=\hat{\text{v}}_\text{in}\exp\left(\varphi\text{j}\right)\tag8$$
- $$\text{R}_0=\frac{\text{R}_1\cdot\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}}{\text{R}_1+\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}}=\frac{\text{R}_1}{1+\omega\text{C}\text{R}_1\text{j}}\tag9$$
- $$\text{R}_4=\text{R}_\text{x}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}\tag{10}$$

Applying this to your circuit, gives:

$$\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{A}}-\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{B}}=\hat{\text{v}}_\text{in}\exp\left(\varphi\text{j}\right)\cdot\left\{\frac{\text{R}_2}{\frac{\text{R}_1}{1+\omega\text{C}\text{R}_1\text{j}}+\text{R}_2}-\frac{\text{R}_\text{x}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}}{\text{R}_3+\text{R}_\text{x}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}}\right\}\tag{11}$$

Comment: *Well, **we** have the following circuit:* Ehrm... who is *we*? OP has quite a different circuit...

Comment: @Huisman Now it does!

Comment: Wait now I see what you're doing... You're combining your impedances C1 and R1 into a single variable, Lx and Rx into a single variable, etc. That may cause confusion because R's nomenclature is resistance.

Comment: @KingDuken Edited!